# how to insert an element into an order array

Tags: java, arrays, insertion, sorting

let's say I have an array of ints that is sorted in ascending order, and I want to insert a new number and I know at what position to insert it. How could I use System.arraycopy.

```
System.arraycopy(items, i, items, i + 1, items.length+1);
items[i] = n;
```

or would I have to create a temp array copy from the position(moving the position one element) of insertion to the temp array, and then copy back to the original array

```
int[] newItems = new int[size + 1];
System.arraycopy(items, i, newItems, i + 1, items.length+1);
items[i] = s;
size++;
System.arraycopy(items, 0, newItems, i, i);
items = newItems;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first way will work.

If you're not confident, see the documentation on arraycopy [arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29). If source and destination are the same, it will act as if copied to a temporary array which is then copied back into the original array, so you can be confident that it'll work!

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts/observations

- Why ask what you can easily test?
- First way might throw IndexOutOfBounds (wont work then)

  - Because in the original array there is no place for another item
  - Because length of copied segment can be at most items.length - i -1 (there will be length-i at the insertion point and after, must drop last one or else have that exception).
- Second way will fail as well. It looks like you are mistaking length for last position.